# Can the `UnsafePointer` mechanism reveal an array of vectors in a Data buffer for use in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, unsafe-pointers

I have a binary file that contains many triples of `Float` values; it is actually a long array of `SCNVector3` representing the vertices for a `SCNGeometrySource`.  I read the file (excuse the omission of do-try-catch, etc) into memory:

```
let sceneVectors = Data(contentsOf: sceneURL)
```

and want to pass that in memory data as a `[SCNVector3]` along to SceneKit:

```
let sceneGeometry = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: sceneVectors)
```

I've been wrestling today with using the `UnsafePointer` mechanism to re-type the contents of `Data` buffer as an array of `SCNVector3` to satisfy the `SCNGeometrySource` contract; something like this.

```
dataBuffer.withUnsafeBytes { 
    (vertexBuffer: UnsafePointer<SCNVector3>) -> SCNGeometry in
        « magic happens here »
        return sceneGeometry
}
```

My reading about this tells me that, within the closure, the buffer can be accessed as an array of `SCNVector3`, but when passed to `SCNGeometrySource` it causes Swift to report:

```
cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<SCNVector3>' to expected argument type '[SCNVector3]'
```

As usual, I suspect there is a simple solution that I've not figured out yet, so I would appreciate any suggestion for resolving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SCNGeometrySource(vertices: sceneVectors)` you have to pass
an *array* of vectors, not a pointer:

```
let sceneGeometry = dataBuffer.withUnsafeBytes {
    (vertexBuffer: UnsafePointer<SCNVector3>) -> SCNGeometrySource in
    let sceneVectors = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: vertexBuffer, count: dataBuffer.count/MemoryLayout<SCNVector3>.stride))
    return SCNGeometrySource(vertices: sceneVectors)
}
```

In Swift 3 (but not in Swift 4 anymore) `SCNGeometrySource` has another initializer which takes a pointer to `SCNVector3` and a count:

```
let sceneGeometry = dataBuffer.withUnsafeBytes {
    (vertexBuffer: UnsafePointer<SCNVector3>) -> SCNGeometrySource in
    return SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertexBuffer, count: dataBuffer.count/MemoryLayout<SCNVector3>.stride)
}
```

which can be shorted to

```
let sceneGeometry = dataBuffer.withUnsafeBytes {
    SCNGeometrySource(vertices: $0, count: dataBuffer.count/MemoryLayout<SCNVector3>.stride)
}
```

Comment: Elegantly described, thanks.  I'll note that the initializer which takes a pointer to `SCNVector3` and a count is not available in Swift 4.  The error is "error: 'init(vertices:count:)' is unavailable in Swift: Use init(vertices:) instead" ..

Comment: I should note, for future readers, that the very first sentence of original post contains an error.  I implied `SCNVector3` is a triple of `Float` when it actually is a triple of `Double`. My file actually does contains `Float` values (using 64-bit values seemed a tad excessive for SceneKit vector) so I still have some work to do, however Martin correctly answered the question I asked.

Comment: @RamsayConsulting: According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnvector3 it is CGFloat on the Mac and Float on iOS.

Comment: Either way they are 64-bit values on 64-bit CPUs.  My file would work out the box with your code, on a 32-bit CPU .. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat

Comment: Of course, if I want to avoid a buffer copy, I can [must?] revert to the rather ghastly `SCNGeometrySource(data: semantic: vectorCount: usesFloatComponents: componentsPerVector: bytesPerComponent: dataOffset: dataStride: )` usage.

Comment: @RamsayConsulting: That sounds sensible –  I admit that I answered the question but know almost nothing about SceneKit and SCNGeometrySource :)